# Смайлики юникод

Tags: unicode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема? В чат и в базу вместо смайликов unicode, типа: ☺
Вставляется: ????
Кодировка базы utf8mb4_unicode_ci (была utf8_unicode_ci я изменил)
При тех же условиях на локалке они отображались.

Comment: Не забыли изменить кодировку всех клиентов и кодировку phpmyadmin?

Comment: все таблицы да, а кодировка phpmyadmin где меняется?